# Single sign out Filter settings in.Net

Tags: asp.net, cas

The article

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+Single+Sign+Out

explains how to configure single sign out in JAVA. Is there any similar way to configure and set filters when using DotNetCasClient and Asp.net. My application uses SAML 1.1 protocol.

Thanks.

Comment: For Single Sign out in .net in web.config add a key <add key="CASurl" value="http://AUS-VC-BDPC-TS1:8100/cas/logout?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.argolimited.com%2Fpages%2Fhome"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did find answer to it:
For Single Sign out in .net in web.config add a key under  named say "CAsUrl":
The value would be the CAS server URL with service parameter pointing to the URL you want to redirect after log out. 
Use this key in your application where you redirect after log out.